# Unable to do plus operation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var timestamp      = $('#timestamp').val();
var timestampLimit = timestamp + 10;
```

But if I alert timestamps it's e.g. for **1382521365**

timestamp will be correct  **1382521365**

However, timestampLimit is **138252136510** insead of **1382521375**

How to fix that?

Comment: Use `parseInt($('#timestamp').val(), 10)`

Answer (score 4):

Input values are stored as strings, so the `+` operator will perform string concatenation rather than arithmetic addition. Use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to convert it to an integer:

```
var timestamp = parseInt($('#timestamp').val(), 10);
var timestampLimit = timestamp + 10;
```

Comment: What does the 10 parameter stand for at the end?

Comment: @CBroe This website is not about links. Please, read the FAQ. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesPriceless That's the radix, which indicates which base the number the string represents is in. So a radix of 10 indicates that it's a decimal number, rather than octal, hexadecimal, etc. You need to specify it because the behaviour when it's undefined isn't consistent between browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Type cast time stamp to `Number`.

```
var timestamp = Number($('#timestamp').val());
var timestampLimit = timestamp + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Number() for the first line of the code...............

```
var timestamp = Number($('#timestamp').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string with numbers, you can force js to cast it to Number using `+` operator like this ..

```
// alerts 130
alert+(  10 + +('120px'.replace('px','')));
// would alert 10120 without plus leading + sign
```